# findOne() in TypeORM not working properly and giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to get the prospectousId from Dto, but I am getting the below error:,

[image: Error]

tenant.controller.ts

```
@Post('/promote-prospectus')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Promoting a prospectus to a tenant.' })
  @ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK, description: 'successful operation', })
  async promoteAProspectus(@Res() response: Response, @Body() Dto: promoteProspectousDto) {
    let result = await this.tenantsService.promoteAProspectus(Dto);
    return response.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).json({ message: 'Prospectous promoted as a tenant by the system.', data: result });
  }
```

tenant.service.ts

```
 public async promoteAProspectus(Dto: promoteProspectousDto): Promise<Tenants> {
    /**
     * Scopes to be implement while promoting a prospectous to a tenant.
     * 
     * @scope 1 promote the prospectous to a tenant and construct DB.
     * @scope 2 Configure all default roles for the newly created tenant.
     * @scope 3 Configure administrator user. & assign the administrator role.
     *
     */

    let prospectus = await this.tenantsRepository.findOne({ Dto.prospectousId });
    console.log('hyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', prospectus);
    if (prospectus) {
      const { id } = prospectus;
      // let tenant: Tenants = await this.promoteAsTenant(prospectus);
      // await this.rolesService.onBoardTenantDefaultRoles(tenant.tenantDb);
      // let administrator: Users = await this.onBoardAdministratorUser(RequestedBy);
      // await this.allocateAdministratorRole(administrator, tenant);
      return tenant;
    }

    throw new ConflictException(`Unable to promote.`);
  }
```

tenant.entity.ts

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

export enum ETenantStatus {
    TRIAL = 'TRIAL',
    ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE',
    BLOCKED = 'BLOCKED',
    ARCHIVED = 'ARCHIVED',
}

@Entity({ name: `${Tenants.name}` })
export class Tenants {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    organization: string;

    @Column({ unique: false })
    db: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    key: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    domain: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    location: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    referedBy: string;

    @Column()
    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp without time zone' })
    public createdAt: Date;

    @Column()
    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp without time zone' })
    public updatedAt: Date;
}
```

dto:

```
   import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsBoolean, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class tenantsDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true, default: '' })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    organization: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true, default: '' })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    domain: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: '' })
    notes: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: '' })
    db: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: '' })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    key: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: '' })
    location: string;


    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: '' })
    referedBy: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ default: false })
    skipDbMigration: boolean;

    @ApiProperty({ default: true })
    @IsBoolean()
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: boolean;
}

export class promoteProspectousDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true, default: '' })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    prospectousId: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true, default: '' })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    key: string;
}
```

What to do  to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `anything({ Dto.prospectousId })` is invalid JavaScript syntax. Something like `{ id }` is shorthand for `{ id: id }` but when you use `Dto.prospectousId` it doesn't really work as a shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code. `findOne()` is to be replaced by `findOneBy()` as they say in their changelog.

```js
let prospectus = await this.tenantsRepository.findOneBy({ id: Dto.prospectousId });
```

See the [Changelog](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1) of TypeORM for more:

> `findOne()` signature without parameters was dropped. If you need a single row from the db you can use a following syntax:
>
> ```js
> const [user] = await userRepository.find()
> ```

> `findOne(id)` signature was dropped. Use following syntax instead:
>
> ```js
> const user = await userRepository.findOneBy({
>    id: id // where id is your column name
> })
> ```

Comment: What if I want to get the relations with it? findOneBy doesn't allow it

findOne(options: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity | null>;

findOneBy(where: FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[]): Promise<Entity | null>;